# Run shell commands as root and detect failed password attempts with python

Tags: python, shell

I have a python function I wrote that can run shell commands as root using subprocess. I'm trying to add functionality to that to detect incorrect password attempts. Here's the function.

```
local_pass = None

def runShellCommandAsRoot(cmd):
    global local_pass
    if local_pass == None:
        print "Enter admin user's password."
        local_pass = getpass.getpass()

    cmd = "echo {} | sudo -S {}".format(local_pass, cmd)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
```

This works fine. What I tried adding to detect failed password attempts was parsing the stderr but I would get different results on each loop. See code below (this I tried adding to the function above):

```
for i in range(5):
    if err == "Password:Sorry, try again.\nPassword:\nsudo: 1 incorrect password attempt\n":
        print "Enter admin user's password."
        local_pass = getpass.getpass()
        cmd = "echo {} | sudo -S {}".format(local_pass, cmd)
        sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = sp.communicate()
    elif err == None or err == "":
        return out, err
        break
    if i == 4:
        print "Exceeded password attempts."
        exit()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the sudo log have this already?

Answer (score 1):

A friend helped me figure out a better solution to run shell commands and also cover error checking for user password! See below:

```
def run_shell_command_as_root(cmd):
    cmd[:0] = ['sudo']
    if not authenticate():
        print 'Unable to authenticate'
        sys.exit(1)
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return sp.communicate()

def authenticate():
    pwd = ''
    for i in range(5):
        sp = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', '-v'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        sp.communicate(pwd + '\n')
        if sp.returncode == 0:
            return True
        if i == 0:
            print "Please enter user password."
        else:
            print "Incorrect password. Please try again."
        pwd = getpass.getpass()
    return False
```